# How to change the color of a string before inserting it at the current position of the cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I get this output while trying to change the color of the string I would like to add in my editor.
The css part is not taken into account. It is added as a simple html. What could be the problem ?

```
some text <font color="green">ADD THIS VALUE</font> some text  and ...
```

Here are the add functions

```
function add_str(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var elt = document.getElementById("text_write");
  insertAtCursor(elt, "ADD THIS VALUE");
}

function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
  myValue = myValue.fontcolor("green");
  if (myField.setRangeText) {
    myField.setRangeText(myValue)
  } else {
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, myValue);
  }
}
```

and the html part

```
<button onmousedown="add_str(event)">
add srting
</button>

<div contenteditable="true" id="text_write" style="height:200px; width:500px; border:2px solid black;">some text some text  and ...</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The `<font>` tag has been depreciated for quite some time. You should style a `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add_str(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var coloredstring = "ADD THIS VALUE"
  var colorofstring = "green"
  var node = document.getElementById("text_write")
  var addedstring = '<span style="color:' + colorofstring + '">' + coloredstring + '</span>'
  node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + addedstring
}
```

```html
<button onmousedown="add_str(event)">
add srting
</button>

<div contenteditable="true" id="text_write" style="height:200px; width:500px; border:2px solid black;">some text some text  and ..</div>
```

font tag no longer works on html5, i did a little hack using a span tag

Comment: Thank you @Jaipi. It works well here. But nor on my Mozilla Firefox. It adds *${coloredstring}*

Comment: change the format of the string to something like '<span style="color:'+colorofstring+'>'+coloredstring+'</span>'

Comment: Hello @Jaipi, Unfortunately, nothing is being added when I change the previous code line to this one.

Comment: i swapped the code on the answer snippet, tested on both chrome and firefox

Comment: Thx @Jaipi, `function add_str(event) { 
  event.preventDefault()
  var coloredstring = "ADD THIS VALUE"
  var colorofstring = "green"
  var node = document.getElementById("text_write")
  var addedstring = '<span style="color:' + colorofstring + '">' + coloredstring + '</span>'
  insertAtCursor(node, addedstring);
}`
I have removed : 
`myValue = myValue.fontcolor("green");`  from here  `insertAtCursor()`

Could you please tell me, why the css part is not taken into account now ? The hole line is added.

I have also tried by adding .innerHTML to the addedstring, but nothing happens.

Comment: Add a snippet of the code to better understand your question

Comment: Hello @Jaipi, I have created a new question. [here]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668283/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-string-while-inserting-it-in-a-div-at-the-current-p)