# How to change the color of a string while inserting it in a div at the current position of the cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of a string before adding it to a div. But the css part is not taken into account. It adds

```
<span style="color:green">ADD THIS VALUE</span>
```

at the cursor position, instead of only adding  `ADD THIS VALUE` in blue 
 What am I missing ?
Here is the snippet of the code.

```js
function add_str(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var coloredstring = "ADD THIS VALUE"
  var colorofstring = "green"
  var node = document.getElementById("text_write")
  var addedstring = '<span style="color:' + colorofstring + '">' + coloredstring + '</span>'
  insertAtCursor(node, addedstring);
}

function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
  if (myField.setRangeText) {
    myField.setRangeText(myValue)
  } else {
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, myValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onmousedown="add_str(event)">add srting</button>

<div contenteditable="true" id="text_write" style="height:200px; width:500px; border:2px solid black;">some text some text and ..</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `insertText` to `insertHTML`:

```js
function add_str(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var coloredstring = "ADD THIS VALUE"
  var colorofstring = "green"
  var node = document.getElementById("text_write")
  var addedstring = '<span style="color:' + colorofstring + '">' + coloredstring + '</span>'
  insertAtCursor(node, addedstring);
}

function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
  if (myField.setRangeText) {
    myField.setRangeText(myValue)
  } else {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, myValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onmousedown="add_str(event)">add srting</button>

<div contenteditable="true" id="text_write" style="height:200px; width:500px; border:2px solid black;">some text some text and ..</div>
```